# Facebook messenger API bot : "Typing bubble" " indicator bubble"

Tags: api, bots, facebook-messenger

I've created a messenger bot, and some action that I perform can take some time. So in order to make the user wait I would like to display the "Indicator Bubble" (the one you see when the people you talk with are typing):

#### Typing bubble

[image]

It is not defined in the Messenger API documentation how to do it, but it seems possible has they perform it when you hit "callBack" on their card.

How can I simulate this?

Answer (score 18):

It's now available into the messenger bot API via the Sender Action. You can find the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/sender-actions).

It's just a post with an on or off value to display / hide the bubble indicator.

```
{
    "recipient":{
          "id":"USER_ID"
    },
    "sender_action":"typing_on" // typing_off
}
```

Comment: What is the USER_ID, is it for the FB account that created the page of the Bot, or is it an ID of the bot itself?

Comment: No it's the ID of the user your bot is talking to. The sender parameter of a message your bot has received (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message-received)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the only way.

When you have the Button Template and someone clicks on "button" for "postback" ([documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference#guidelines) in section "button template").

Then during your parsing of the message and sending answer, it is shown like "writing".

Comment: But do you think there is a work around to achieve the same result without the user hitting a "postback button" ? My point is that it can be frustrating for the user to wait the bot answer. But if there is the bubble showing that the bot is actually processing something, the user will wait and not firing new message thinking that the bot didn't get it.

Comment: @HenriChabrand I have the same issue, did you find a workaround ?

Comment: No, I didn't find any workaround yet. I let you know if I have better luck on other forum.

Answer (score 0):

The official messenger API does not support this feature for now. Even if [@hiponcho](https://www.messenger.com/t/hiponcho/) – one of the featured by Facebook chatbot is actually using it.

A workaround would be to use the unofficial messenger API, which has a method called [`sendTypingIndicator`](https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api/blob/master/DOCS.md#sendTypingIndicator) that does exactly what you want. But be careful, you can be banned for using of non-official API.

`api.sendTypingIndicator(threadID, [callback])`

Answer (score -1):

I know it is a hack, but currently I send the "Typing Bubble Indicator" as a animated gif as my first reply, if I anticipate a waiting time (like an API call). At the user end, you can't tell the difference.